# Trouble connecting to Oracle using my own class library

Tags: .net, vb.net, oracle

I wrote a code that reads data using ***Oracle.DataAccess.Client*** (works perfectly).
When I compile the same code as DLL and call the function I suddenly get a runtime error that reads:

> The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle Client

I downloaded the Oracle.DataAccess from NuGet by running this command:

> Install-Package ODP.NET4 -Version 4.112.3

The .Net Framework is version 4.6.2. In both projects I am referencing my DLLs from bin folders.

Here is my code:

```
Public Shared Function ReturnTheValue(ByVal ConnString As String,ByVal SQL As String) As DataTable
        Dim DT As New DataTable("Data")
        Using Conn As New OracleConnection(ConnString )
            Dim cmd As New OracleCommand(SQL, Conn)
            Dim Da As New OracleDataAdapter(cmd)
            Da.Fill(DT)
            Conn.Close()
        End Using
        Return DT
 End Function
```

Comment: Did you install the Oracle Client in the same architecture (32-bit vs. 64-bit)? Is it (**exactly**) the same version as the ODP.NET?

Comment: Yes I did all that

Comment: Use [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) or [fuslogvw.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer) to check which DLL is actually loaded and if it matches the Oracle client.